# Drupal 7 local font

Tags: drupal, fonts

I have a problem with my local fonts in Drupal 7.

What I've done:

1. I added the module `@font-your-face` to the folder `/sites/all/modules/fontyourface`
2. I enabled the module on my website
3. I added the files to the module (via the website)
4. I configured the css-selectors settings

Everything was working, and the font was added to my website. But when I pushed locally (via git bash), it didn't work anymore. In appearance > @fontyourface I can still see my local font and it is enabled, but it looks like he can't find it anymore. Also the preview isn't correct anymore.

I think that I need to add the .eot and the .woff files somewhere in my filesystem of the website but I don't know where. I tried `/sites/all/modules/fontyourface/modules/local_fonts` but that doesn't work.

Comment: odd that pushing on git changes anything, did you check the javascript console in Chrome (f12) to see if the page failed to load a file? Or you could look in the network tab. Also did you clear the drupal cache?

Comment: I can't see any strange things in the console... And I cleared the cash with drush.